# IntelliSense, Go to Definition, Docstring display only works for subset of opened documents

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Expected behaviour:
Ability to use IntelliSense autocomplete, Go to Definition feature, Docstring display on hover, etc.

Actual behaviour:
The features mentioned above only works on a subset of open documents (usually only one)

Example repro:
I opened two golang files in the same session. In the example below I get expected behavior for server3/main.go but do not get expected behavior for server2/main.go. The behavior is not deterministic in the sense that sometimes the behavior can be flipped between between two files.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ExFE.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4zPP.png)

EDIT: I found that the features only work on a single bottom level folder. Does anyone know how to make the features works across all sub-folders in my open session?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/settings.md#buildexperimentalworkspacemodule ?

```
"gopls": {
   "build.experimentalWorkspaceModule": true
}
```

For backgrounds: https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md#multiple-modules